# Is it possible to compare two Immutable.js maps with logarithmic runtime complexity?

Tags: immutable.js

## Context

Imagine you have a data structure that is changing over time. This data structure could be of any arbitrary shape, but for now let's assume we will represent it with an Immutable.js `Map`. As changes come in, new maps are created (i.e., `map1`, `map2`, `map3`, etc.) Because Immutable.js data structures are persistent, most of the data within the maps will be shared.

Now imagine you have some listeners that are subscribed to changes to this map, but instead of changes to the overall map, they only care about specific entries in it. Because Immutable.js represents these data structures internally with a trie, it is possible to determine what changed between the two maps in logarithmic time. The reason is that the trie prefixes will not change across maps if their leaf nodes are the same.

## Question

Is it possible to leverage the internal trie data structure to do this comparison for changed entries in logarithmic time or is it necessary for one to implement their own trie? Could Immutable.js provide a method to compare two data structures and return a set of changes (i.e., what was removed, what was changed, and what was added)?